# Spring HATEOAS - two same links

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

lately I've been doing some projekt with Spring Data and Rest with HATEOAS.

My question is, is it normal, that in entity links secion, I have 2 same links?

[image]

Here is repository:

[Repository](https://github.com/Savek/user-service)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. But it's not always the case: the 'user' link is actually a templated link that gets enriched in certain cases.

For instance, should you define the following [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts):

```
@Projection(name = "summary", types = { User.class }) 
interface Summary { 

  String getUsername(); 
  String getEmail();

}
```

then the `user` link would show the projection parameter:

```
...
"_links" : {
  "self" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/1"
  },
  "user" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/1{?projection}"
    "templated" : true
  }
```

And you could be able to get a summary of user 1 by GETting `http://localhost:8080/users/1?projection=summary`.

Comment: You are right, but consider a case in which there is no projection, it is simply redundancy.

Comment: Can't argue with that, even though I assume it is the wanted behavior (two links with the same href value), possibly for semantic reasons, or related to the discoverability of the HATEOAS resources.

Comment: Is it redundancy? If a client built itself up on navigating the "user", to suddenly remove the link might be viewed as brittle. Semantically, "self" is a canonical reference to itself, kind of like a "this" pointer for resources. While "user" is the link to a richer opportunity, that might alter depending on the server. So while the values may appear the same, their semantics can indicate different things.