# Why spring create tow identical links for self and rel?

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I cannot get why spring create the same links for *self* and *rel*? Is there a way how to disable it? I think that this only my issue because I didn't meet such problem in docs I read.

[image]

Here is my entity mapping:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document
public class Ad {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String description;
    private Banner banner;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Banner {
    private String id;
    private String filename;
}
```

Here is my repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AdRepository extends CrudRepository<Ad, String> {
}
```

I touch the following url: *http://localhost:8558/ads*

I don't use any projections. My app is quite primitive now. There is nothing specific.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your Entity mapping code?

Comment: @szxnyc, sure. it's done

Comment: What does your request look like? Are you using a projection?

Comment: @szxnyc, I answer in the question, please check it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring HATEOAS - two same links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649664/spring-hateoas-two-same-links)

Answer (score 0):

My only guess is that maybe you're missing hashCode/equals and that's causing a problem

Comment: I just checked, it's not caused by hashCode/equals

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. The `rel`-based link allows you to see all contexts, while `self` link serves as the **canonical link**.

To further clarify, adjust your repository definition to extend not `CrudRepository`, but instead `PagingAndSortingRepository`. The two links rendered for each aggregate root will immediately look slightly different due to extended templating options.